# Webdav windows server 2008 not allowing doc files to save

Tags: windows-server-2008, webdav

I have setup web dav on windows server 2008. It seems to work fine but will not allow me to save a word document to the dir but it will allow a text file to be saved. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found answer at:
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis-70/

Cd c:\ 
cd "%WinDir%\System32\InetSrv"\

AppCmd set config "Default Web Site/documents"" /section:system.webServer/security/requestFiltering

/+fileExtensions.[fileExtension='.doc',allowed='true'] /commit:apphost